# Angular JS Options Dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs

I was wondering with AngularJS ng-options - is it possible to use 2 different variables for the name in the dropdown?

take this simplified example - I would like the dropdown to contain Country - City in the dropdown. I know this is simplistic but is this possible to do with combining the variables outside of the select dropdown?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="HelloController" >

<select ng-model="blah" ng-options="city.Id as city.CityName for city in cities"></select>
</div>
<script>
angular.module("myapp", [])
    .controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
        $scope.cities = [
   {Id: '000001', Country:'USA', CityName: 'Chicago'},
   {Id: '000002', Country:'Ireland', CityName: 'Dublin'},
   {Id: '000003', Country:'Spain', CityName: 'Barcelona'},
   {Id: '000004', Country:'USA', CityName: 'Boston'},
];

    } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish that like so:

```
ng-options="city.Id as (city.Country + ' - '  + city.CityName) for city in cities"
```

Comment: thats was it - sorry for the noob question. Thanks John